# Simulating a touch event in Android in a background thread

Tags: java, android

I have used a service which posts code to a handler at an interval of 3 seconds to keep generating a simple touch event (a button press).

This is the service code:

```
public class BackgroundTouchService extends IntentService
{
    public BackgroundTouchService() {
        super("BackgroundTouchService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS, 400, 400, 0);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run()
           {
               View v = new View(getApplication());
               v.onTouchEvent(event);
               handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

In my UI, I have covered the screen with buttons (with appropriate listeners) so that I can easily spot which button has been pressed. However, the main activity loads up and then nothing happens. Why is this?

EDIT:
As Vojtěch Sáze correctly pointed out, the handler in the above code is not associated with the main thread, and hence cannot be used to modify the UI by generating touch events. Hence, I wrote the code for the handler in the main activity itself:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startTouch();
}

private void startTouch()
{
    final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS,400.0f, 400.0f, 0);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                onTouchEvent(event);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, this still does not do anything. Any ideas?

SOLUTION:
Okay, so in the event type parameter of the MotionEvent.obtain method I had originally specified ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS, however, when I used to separate events to specify ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP separately, this seemed to work.
Any explanations as to why this happened are welcome.
In case someone needs this, here is the code:

```
final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,400.0f, 400.0f, 0);
        final MotionEvent event2 = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 400.0f, 400.0f, 0);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            dispatchTouchEvent(event2);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use dispatchTouchEvent method to send the touch event to the view.

Comment: Which view does this method send the touch event to? We call it without an object.

Comment: When you call it without an object, the method call will be on "this". So i think in your case it will be activity instance. I thought i knew about how events propagation happens in android, but i got some concepts wrong. I came across this video that explains very clearly how events move from parent to child. Please go thru it,  https://newcircle.com/s/post/1567/mastering_the_android_touch_system

Comment: Actually the touch event that I generated is confined to the activity (like you correctly pointed out, this is because dispatchTouchEvent() is called on the activity object. However, I actually want to generate system wide touch events. That is, touch events that keep running even when the activity is closed. So if I close the activity and go to the home screen, then the touch event should continue executing and click some icon on the home screen. Do you know how I can do this? This probably requires a modification to the dispatchTouchEvent() method.

Comment: Sorry, system wide touch events would render Android completely insecure. It's not possible to do that, you would need root for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help. But definitely there is problem with

```
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler()):

Default constructor associates this handler with the Looper for the current thread. If this thread does not have a looper, this handler won't be able to receive messages so an exception is thrown.

But you don't have main thread in `onHandleIntent()`. You'll need to create the `Handler` in the main thread.

Comment: You're right. The handler has to be associated with the main thread if it has to generate touch events (which is classified as modifying the UI, and hence can only be done in the main thread). Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use code below. Using Android Handler, you need also looper for posting action.

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            onTouchEvent(event);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    });
```